# Bulk Rename Files in a Folder (php)

Tags: php

im trying to rename multiple images inside folder with numerical number (1.jpg,2.jpg...) with php.
//xampp path ‘htdocs\e4\3’

Following code is renaming files but its adding digit zero ('0') in front after renaming files like: 01.jpg, 02.jpg, 03.jpg

number zero is being added by code below:

```
$newname = str_pad($i, strlen($count), ‘0’, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

but i want simply as : 1.jpg, 2.jpg … 10.jpg,11jpg, 12.jpg

```
function sequentialImages($path, $sort=false) {
$i = 1;
$files = glob($path."/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png}",GLOB_BRACE|GLOB_NOSORT);

if ( $sort !== false ) {
  usort($files, $sort);
}

$count = count($files);
foreach ( $files as $file ) {
$newname = str_pad($i, strlen($count), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$ext = substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1);
$newname = $path.'/'.$newname.'.'.$ext;
if ( $file != $newname ) {
   rename($file, $newname);  
  echo 'file rename';
 }
 $i++;
}
}
sequentialImages(__DIR__);
```

and after rename i want to open the folder(../e4/3)

i tried header location:

```
header("Location:_DIR_");
```

but it didnt worked

Comment: _"but its adding digit zero ('0') in front after renaming files like: 01.jpg, 02.jpg, 03.jpg"_ - well, that's exactly what `$newname = str_pad($i, strlen($count), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` does.

Comment: `header("Location:_DIR_");` - first of all, the constant name uses _two_ underscore characters on either side, and second, you can not use a constant name inside a string like that, it will not automatically get replaced like a variable would. And third, that constant contains a _file system_ path - so in most setups, trying to use that as a URL will not even make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If don't want the proceeding zeros, then use `$i` instead of `str_pad(...)` as `$newname`. So, the definition of `$newname` should look like this:

```php
$newname = $path.'/'.$i.'.'.$ext;
```

Then you can remove the line:

```php
$newname = str_pad($i, strlen($count), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

`header("Location:_DIR_");` would not work, because `__DIR__` can not be interpolated, because it is not a variable. It must be `header("Location: " . __DIR__);`

On the other hand, you should place a URL there instead of local file/directory path. Your URL may absolute `https://example.com/e4/3` or relative to the server root `/e4/3`. The constant `__DIR__` would equal somehow to `/rootOnyoursystem/somesubdir/.../e4/3` which is not a valid URL for your application and can not work.

Here is edited version of your function:

```php
function createSequentialImages($path, $sort=false, $deleteSourceFiles=false) {

    $files = glob($path."/{.gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png}",GLOB_BRACE|GLOB_NOSORT);

    if ( $sort !== false ) {
        usort($files, $sort);
    }

    foreach ( $files as $i => $file ) {

        $fileinfo = pathinfo($file);

        $newname = $path.'/'.($i+1).'.'.$fileinfo['extension'];

        if ( $file == $newname )
            continue;

        if($deleteSourceFiles){
            if(rename($file, $newname))
                echo "\nFile ". basename($file) . " renamed to " . basename($newname);
            else
                echo "\nERROR while renaming file ". basename($file) . "  to " . basename($newname);
        }
        else {
            if(copy($file, $newname))
                echo "\nFile ". basename($file) . " saved as " . basename($newname);
            else
            echo "\nERROR while saving file ". basename($file) . "  as " . basename($newname);
        }
    }
}

createSequentialImages(__DIR__);
```

Comment: function sequentialImages($path, $sort=false) {
$i = 1;
$files = glob($path."/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png}",GLOB_BRACE|GLOB_NOSORT);
if ( $sort !== false ) {
  usort($files, $sort);
}
$count = count($files);
foreach ( $files as $file ) {
$ext = substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1);
$newname = $path.'/'.$i.'.'.$ext;
if ( $file != $newname ) {
   rename($file, $newname);  
  echo 'file rename';
 }
 $i++;
}
}
sequentialImages(__DIR__);
but on refresh its changes number like 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 8.jpg and delete file too.
$ext = substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1); may by this line

Comment: @sambhulambhu I updated my answer with edited version of your function. With `...and delete file too.` you mean I believe that the image files with original name are deleted. This is normal because you use `rename()` function. If you rename a file, then you have only the target file. I added an option to save as the files with sequential index.